# Pasting text into Android emulator clipboard using adb shell

Tags: android, emulation, clipboard, copy-paste

I need to paste text into the Android emulator clipboard using adb shell. 
tried on Android 1.6 and 2.3.1

I tried to use adb shell command: clipboard:[android.text.iclipboard]

"service call clipboard" where service codes are 1, 2, and 3, for getClipboardText, setClipboardText, and hasClipboardText respectively.

```
service call clipboard 2 s16 thisisinsertedtext
```

does not seem to work
while

```
service call clipboard 1
```

shows the content of clipboard:

```
service call clipboard 1
Result: Parcel(
   0x00000000: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000004 '................'
   0x00000010: 00650074 00740078 00000000          't.e.x.t.....    ')
```

Please advise how to set a value for emulator clipboard!

Comment: also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391160/paste-text-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 5):

Use below command.

> service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 18 s16 thisisinsertedtext

I think that the first one, "i32 1" is how many elements in clipboard. So, just one.
Second is a length of string.
The command written above shows...

> Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')
>   This usually means OK, no error.

So, my question is, is there any way to copy unicode string?
I mean, muti-byte character sets, like Korean.
I tried many way, but it failed.

Comment: How can I paste into clipboard 4 worlds? this is inserted text

Comment: I assume you would put the string in quotes.

Comment: This command line works for my Gingerbread emulator, but not for ICS.  The data in the parcel that gets returned says "Unknown package".

Comment: The first i32 is `0` to clear the clipboard, non-zero to set. The code uses ` if ((0!=data.readInt())) ...`. The other i32s encode the spans (i.e. bold) in the text. See the class com.android.server.ClipboardService.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like all 3 **old** methods are deprecated since API Level 11 so it won’t work for ICS
Not clear if it's even possible to make it work with **service call clipboard** anymore...

```
static final int    TRANSACTION_getClipboardText 1
static final int    TRANSACTION_hasClipboardText 3
static final int    TRANSACTION_setClipboardText 2
```

www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/constant-values.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 1):

> adb shell service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 1 s16 "你好吗"
>
> Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')

That is OK.

"你好吗" is Chinese character.

The second 'i32 1' can be any integer, maybe...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

i32: Write the integer INT into the send parcel.

s16: Write the UTF-16 string STR into the send parcel.

Answer (score -1):

Using adb shell command directly do not work since API Level 11.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243427/set-clipboard-text-via-adb-shell-as-of-api-level-11) is a solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is an open source python script that can deal with the severe limitations: https://github.com/gcb/AdbPaste - and it works well enough except for long clipboard file uploads it's incredibly slow (200 line text file can take 20 minutes).

I found some code on GitHub for an app called clipper that can use adb to populate clipboard via a broadcast intent.  I enhanced it to read from a file, the enhanced code is here: https://github.com/RoundSparrow/clipper

Build the app, install on the device. Now I can use ADB commands to populate the clipboard via a file. Works like a charm for a 3 page script I need to upload.  Essentially you use like this:

```
adb push clipboard_content_file.txt /sdcard/clipboard_content_file.txt
adb shell am broadcast -a clipper.setfile -e filepath \'/sdcard/clipboard_content_file.txt\'
```

It's much faster AdbPaste, it takes only a second or two regardless of the size of the clipboard content.