# How to copy some text to android system clipboard using ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-8.0-oreo

I want to automate some stuff on my rooted android Oreo and can't seem to find a way to copy some text to clipboard. I can paste the copied text `adb shell input keyevent 279` so hoping to get some way to copy text also.

P.S: not looking for answers suggesting `adb shell input text [text]` cause it's slow.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14243427/1778421

Comment: I think you want to send some text to clipboard manager of your android device through your desktop and then paste it somewhere in the same android device to make inputting text process faster. Is it what you meant?

Comment: no I use shell terminal app to run the commands. and my phone is rooted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems there are 2 ways to copy a text into android clipboard using `adb shell`.

1. Using `service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 0 s16 "text"` (Deprecated and doesn't work on android 8)
2. Using an external service and pass it the text through intent extras. It receives the text then tries to copy it into the clipboard. For example we can install [Clipper](https://github.com/majido/clipper) on the device then run `am broadcast -a clipper.set -e text "text"` in `adb shell`.

Comment: For Clipper, it doesn't work well on Android from 10 (? - I'm not sure). We need to do a trick that starts the app before calling get (https://github.com/majido/clipper/issues/9#issuecomment-561631540)

Comment: The first way not worked on Android 7