# How to get Android Clipboard text in C#?

Tags: c#, android, adb

The scenario is , I copy something in the android app which stored in to the clipboard. Now, I want that data, so that I can use in my program to verify it.

At-least an adb command to get the clipboard text will be enough. I can use some c# library to run that adb command and will get the data in programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy some text to android system clipboard using ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130653/how-to-copy-some-text-to-android-system-clipboard-using-adb)

Comment: @shingo If I understand the question correctly your linked question is the opposite direction (write data to clipboard instead of read data from clipboard).

Comment: I want to read data from clipboard...