# adb + android: access app-produced clipboard data programmatically in Linux terminal

Tags: android, adb

**Setup**

I'm on an `Android 10` device and have an app (henceforth **generator**) that generates data it can copy to the device's clipboard (this involves swipes, taps, etc.). I need to do that repeatedly, as many times as possible (hundreds, thousands, whatever), and retrieve that data programmatically (presumably through a `bash` or `perl` script wrapped around `adb` commands).

**Question**

What would be some effective ways of achieving this?

**Elaboration on what I've tried**

I actually have a solution, I am just not sure it's the "best" one can do (whatever that means). **generator** is closed-source so I can't alter *its* behavior in any way, but I can repeatedly

1. start **generator** and/or switch focus to it [with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25398877/11064961)

```
adb shell monkey -p <generator-app> 1
```

2. mimic the tapping actions that produce the data and copy it to the clipboard [with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351854/11064961) various

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

commands;

3. open/switch focus to the [Termux](https://termux.com/) terminal emulator (on the Android device):

```
adb shell monkey -p com.termux 1
```

4. access the clipboard via its [Termux:API add-on](https://github.com/termux/termux-api), by running the `termux-clipboard-get` command in the `termux` terminal (again, on the Android device). I control this through `adb` with

```
adb shell input text 'termux-clipboard-get\>\>file-on-android-gadget.txt' && adb shell input keyevent 66
```

(keyevent 66 [means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/11064961) `ENTER`, and the `\>\>` means append, `>>`, with escaped characters).

5. repeat the whole shebang.

This gives me many instances of the desired output in `file-on-android-gadget.txt`, saved locally on the phone (I'm OK retrieving it later, etc.).

**Alternative routes?**

What bothers me is the need to switch back and forth between two apps. I don't know that I have much choice over how I interact with **generator**, as it's closed-source and does not expose its internals, but perhaps one can do better at "the other end", i.e. when retrieving the clipboard data.

Newer Android APIs [have locked down](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/03/14/android-q-will-kill-clipboard-manager-apps-in-the-name-of-privacy/) access to the clipboard, rendering it difficult to interact with programmatically, through `adb`. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243427/set-clipboard-text-via-adb-shell-as-of-api-level-11) points to [a repo](https://github.com/micer/clipboard-service) for a (Kotlin + gradle) app that *sets* the clipboard via a service runnable through `adb`, but my attempts to *get* the clipboard have been unsuccessful (i.e. `getPrimaryClip()` returns empty). I believe this is because, as per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager#getPrimaryClip()):

> getPrimaryClip
>
> public ClipData getPrimaryClip ()
>
> Returns the current primary clip on the clipboard. If the application
> is not the default IME or does not have input focus this return null.

So there might just be no way around having to *focus* on a second app before the clipboard can be retrieved. But I have no experience programming apps, hence the question.

**A further reference**

During my peregrinations I found [another repo](https://github.com/majido/clipper) for an Android app (Java + maven) that both gets and sets the clipboard. Same caveat though: as of Android 10, it [needs to be](https://github.com/majido/clipper/issues/9) in focus for the broadcast receiver to retrieve the clipboard data (other than that it works fine; I have it on my Android 10 device as we speak). So this would fare no better than my currently-working termux-based solution detailed above.