# Set up adb on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, adb

I spent quite sometime figuring how to set up adb on Mac, so I figure writing how to set it up might be useful to some people. adb is the command line tool to install and run android apps on your phone/emulator

Comment: And here I thought "adb"is an old Unix debugger! ;)  http://books.google.com/books?id=az-df5bhb1YC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22adb%22+%22a+debugger%22+-android+%22unix%22&source=bl&ots=t-C4M7bv0b&sig=sI03zrFtNTDTksA1JBzGCasj9I4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ymv0UbC-JY-r4AOcpIG4DA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22adb%22%20%22a%20debugger%22%20-android%20%22unix%22&f=false

Comment: There is a link to the official `platform-tools` SDK package (which contains the `adb` binary) at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info

Answer (score 1846, accepted):

*Note: this was originally written on [Installing ADB on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/) but that question was closed as a duplicate of this one.*

*Note for **zsh users**: replace all references to `~/.bash_profile` with `~/.zshrc`.*

## Option 1 - Using Homebrew

This is the easiest way and will provide automatic updates.

1. Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install adb

   ```
   brew install android-platform-tools
   ```

   or try a cask install depending on your settings:

   ```
   brew install --cask android-platform-tools
   ```
3. Start using adb

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

## Option 2 - Manually (just the platform tools)

This is the easiest way to get a manual installation of ADB and Fastboot.

1. Delete your old installation *(optional)*

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.android-sdk-macosx/
   ```
2. Navigate to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html and click on the `SDK Platform-Tools for Mac` link.
3. Go to your Downloads folder

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
4. Unzip the tools you downloaded

   ```
   unzip platform-tools-latest*.zip
   ```
5. Move them somewhere you won't accidentally delete them

   ```
   mkdir ~/.android-sdk-macosx
   mv platform-tools/ ~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
   ```
6. Add `platform-tools` to your path

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal app)

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
8. Start using adb

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

## Option 3 - If you already have Android Studio installed

1. Add `platform-tools` to your path

   ```
   echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile
   echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal app)

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
3. Start using adb

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

## Option 4 - MacPorts

1. Install the Android SDK:

   ```
   sudo port install android
   ```
2. Run the SDK manager:

   ```
   sh /opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
   ```
3. Uncheck everything but `Android SDK Platform-tools` *(optional)*
4. Install the packages, accepting licenses. Close the SDK Manager.
5. Add `platform-tools` to your path; in MacPorts, they're in `/opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools`.  E.g., for bash:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
6. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal/shell):

   source ~/.bash_profile
7. Start using adb:

   adb devices

## Option 5 - Manually (with SDK Manager)

1. Delete your old installation *(optional)*

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.android-sdk-macosx/
   ```
2. Download the Mac SDK Tools from the Android developer site under ["Get just the command line tools"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#mac-tools). Make sure you save them to your Downloads folder.
3. Go to your Downloads folder

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
4. Unzip the tools you downloaded

   ```
   unzip tools_r*-macosx.zip
   ```
5. Move them somewhere you won't accidentally delete them

   ```
   mkdir ~/.android-sdk-macosx
   mv tools/ ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools
   ```
6. Run the SDK Manager

   ```
   sh ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
   ```
7. Uncheck everything but `Android SDK Platform-tools` *(optional)*

   [image]
8. Click `Install Packages`, accept licenses, click `Install`. Close the SDK Manager window.

   [image]
9. Add `platform-tools` to your path

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
10. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal app)

    ```
    source ~/.bash_profile
    ```
11. Start using adb

    ```
    adb devices
    ```

Comment: this is far more straightforward than chasing down the sdk path which keeps changing.

Comment: Has now moved to cask: brew cask install android-platform-tools

Comment: For create file if not available perform with terminal
$Touch .bash_profile

For open and edit file

$open -e .bash_profile
in file type it
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user_name/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH 

then file>save
After restart Terminal app and enjoy.

Comment: Option 1 worked fastest and smoother. Can I give you an award for saving my time :) Thanks!

Comment: please consider editing your post to rearrange the options order. as it currently stands it seem to suggest that using `homebrew` is the recommended option. it may be the easiest option to install but for a novice developer it should be skipped in favor of the official Google binaries (options #2 and #3)

Comment: If you already have android studio installed, option 1 is not a solution as android studio updates faster than android-platform-tools on android. There will be a mismatch and it won't run correctly.

Comment: Option 3. Note that you need to have downloaded AND installed AND ran Android Studio (for the first time), for it to install the SDK Tools. If you had just downloaded (the dmg) or just downloaded and installed but not run, then the SDK Tools will not be present (yet), until you run it for the first time.

Comment: I already have Android studio so I tried 3. It works after I run source ./bash_profile but only persists as long as the terminal is open.

Comment: @Bikram you need to make sure ./bash_profile is always run when your terminal starts up. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically

Comment: Yes! This! Thank you! Why is this not done by default when using Android Studio? Jeez, there are so many additional unnecessary steps just to get a functioning environment!

Comment: On MacOS Catalina and higher settings should be exported to .zprofile .

Comment: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

worked for me, thanks

Comment: Hi! I have android studio on Mac, I have ANDROID_JOME setup on zhrc but none of this work. adb command is still not found. can someone please help me.

Comment: @SMDC is that a typo or are you actually putting in ANDROID_JOME instead of ANDROID_HOME?

Answer (score 612):

`echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

If you put the android-sdks folder in other directory, replace the path with the directory android-sdks/platform-tools is in

Comment: And for those who use `zsh` instead bash, you'll need to add this to `~/.zshrc`

Comment: You've also gotta Quit and reopen your Terminal for the changes to take effect

Comment: As of Android Studio 1.0 Location of platform tools is 

    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[yourusername]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: No need to quit and reopen the Terminal, you can just `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Do you have to install Android Studio first?

Comment: You can use $HOME instead of "/Users/[yourusername]"

Comment: This is a horrific answer as it nukes everything else in your bash_profile

Comment: For other fools ;) who might copy and paste that escaped text directly into their .bash_profile and then wonder where the heck the `which` and other basic commands went after reloading the shell (`source ~/.bash_profile`) : that should read as `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: Best answer I found.

Comment: 2024 update (for new macs):`echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 160):

## Only for zsh users in Terminal or iterm2 in macOS

type the following two commands to add the android sdk and platform-tools to your zsh in Terminal or iterm2 in macOS

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.zshrc
```

After adding the two command to `~/.zshrc` you need to source the zsh.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! :) Thanks! Also, don't forget to run source .zshrc or reopen terminal. :D

Comment: You are welcome. edited the answer and add a source to zsh command.

Comment: What do i need to put instead of the $PATH and $ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: works like a charm on the M1 mac! thank you! I wasn't aware of the zsh and bash thing are now updated. used mac after like 4 years!

Comment: PS not just iTerm2 it works fine in terminal too. So thanks again!

Comment: @sud007 Hello, I am having trouble to run ./adb from terminal with M1 chip, i have followed all the steps and solutions but stil no change, can you please explain how you got it?

Comment: @Ulugbek, I just followed the steps and it just worked fine for me. Did you make sure that you set the right path for `$user/Library` and also have you set your `ANDROID_HOME` as well prior to trying this?

Comment: this is how it works, because when we use homebrew then bash is not the solution

Answer (score 115):

This Works Flawless....

In terminal Run both commands next to each other

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works great as of June 2017 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: `sdk` folder has been removed. If those two commands were run, `adb devices` won't work. Should be the following for latest android studio
`
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
`

Comment: Thanks its help me but make sure change after $USER path with your directory of sdk

Comment: As of android studio 3.2, the path is defaulted to
    '$HOME/Library/Android/sdk'

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot

Comment: Only solution that helped me and was easy to do. Works on MacOS Big Sur. end of 2020!

Comment: On Big Sur....uh...was running these commands supposed to make `adb devices` be globally recognized in terminal? Because it didn't. I have Android Studio installed. Closed and opened a new Terminal window.

Answer (score 70):

## 2022 Solution

If you have Android Studio installed already and Terminal isn't picking up ADB, here's a one-liner that should fix it:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/bin
```

It creates a symbolic link (essentially a shortcut) for the `adb` executable. It's added to `/usr/local/bin` which is one of the default locations where Terminal looks for command line tools.

Comment: Could you explain what happens in this? what is `ln` and `-s`?

Comment: It creates a symbolic link (essentially a shortcut) for the adb executable. It's added to /usr/local/bin which is one of the default locations where Terminal looks for command line tools.

Answer (score 60):

**NOTE: Path for adb has changed since Android Studio 1.0.xx**

For *bash* shell, use:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:'$HOME'/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

For *tcsh* shell, use:

```
echo 'setenv PATH $PATH\:'$HOME'/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.tcshrc
```

Comment: This is indeed where the tools are located in the latest version

Comment: I have 1.0.1 and I don't have anything there :/

Comment: Command for bash shell and Eclipse is echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Android Studio 2.0 and that's still the location - `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

Answer (score 48):

If you are using `zsh shell` and after trying all this solutions, you still need to set `$PATH` and `$ANDROID_HOME` every time you open new terminal instance, then here is your answer:

**step 1:** in terminal run `nano ~/.zshrc`

**step 2:** paste following command at the end of the file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

**step 3:** After copying the lines above, to save hit <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. and to confirm hit <kbd>Y</kbd>. It will ask you if you wish to change the file name but don't change the name so directly hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

**step 4:** Restart your terminal and execute the adb command.

Bingo!

Comment: You might want to use this to be user name independent: export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: @MichaelTroger well said, I've updated the answer with your help! thanks

Comment: To avoid conflicts with vscode use this solution in macos 11 or higher. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72206562/7621800

Comment: Worked for me! This is the best answer!

Answer (score 26):

Personally I just source my .bashrc in my .bash_profile:

```
echo 'source ~/.bashrc' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

So I put it in my .bashrc. And I'm using Android Studio, so it was a different path.

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bashrc
```

You may also want the following:

```
echo 'ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 26):

Here is a step wise information :

> Step-1

Start up Terminal and go to your home folder.

```
cd ~/
```

> Step-2

Open and edit .bash_profile file

```
$ open -e .bash_profile
```

If you don’t have .bash_profile file in your computer path, then create one. Enter below command to create a new file. Once created follow Step-2.

```
touch .bash_profile
```

> Step-3

Save the below line)

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools
```

> Step-4

Refresh the file using below command

```
$ source .bash_profile

$ echo $PATH
```

You should see your android path set in the output now.

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way to use adb command on your Mac systems would be to add the path to the platform-tools (where adb lives) into your bash_profile.

Steps to add the adb path:
1. open the bash_profile: This can be done by using the following commands

`open ~/.bash_profile`

This opens up the bash_profile in an editor.

2. Locate the platform_tools, usually they are present at the following location: Users/"user_folder"/Library/Android/sdk/platform_tools
3. Paste the following command in the bash_profile file which opens up:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/A374375/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`
4. Save the file using the command:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

5. Check if the path is saved by typing: `echo $PATH` : You should be able to find the entire path displayed in the output.
6. Type `adb` to see if the configuration worked. If you have any devices connected to the machine or any emulators running on your system they would be displayed when you type `adb devices`

[output for adb devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuMo3.png)

Answer (score 19):

For Mac users :
Step 1: Install the Android Studio

Step2 : Open the terminal and type

```
cd
```

Step 3: Type below mentioned command changing the userName:

```
export PATH=“/Users/{user_name}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools”:$PATH
```

Answer (score 17):

On MacOS Big Sur do the following:

Open config file:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add paths to PATH variable:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

close file and save changes.
Then in terminal write:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

And then you'll be able to run:

```
adb devices
adb kill-server
```

Answer (score 16):

`cd sdk/platform-tools/` and then use `./adb devices` instead

Comment: I have to be inside `/Users/ashokr/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` and then it works.

Answer (score 11):

### This solution is for Mac:

Considering you have already downloaded SDK platform tools & trying to set **adb** path:

If you want to check the SDK is available or not, just check it by following this path:
User > Library (Hidden folder) > Android > sdk > platform-tools > `adb`

[image: SDK PATH IMAGE]

To set the PATH for the adb command on a macOS system, firstly need to edit your shell configuration file. The default shell on macOS is **Bash** or **Zash**.
If you're using **Bash**, so you will need to edit the **~/.bash_profile** file otherwise edit **~/.zprofile** in your home directory.

## Here's how to do it:

### By Terminal:

1. Open a terminal window and enter the following command:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
nano ~/.zprofile
```

This will open the **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zprofile** file in the Nano text editor.

2. Add the following line to the file:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Press `Ctrl+X` to exit the Nano editor, then press `Y` to save the changes and `Enter` to confirm the filename.

3. Run the following command to reload your shell configuration:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

After you have set the PATH for adb, you should be able to run the adb command from any terminal window.

---

### By Manual:

1. Go to the `Home` directory & tap `command` + `shift` + `.` (To show the hidden files)
   [image: View IMAGE]
2. Search file **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zprofile** & open it.
   [image: View IMAGE]
3. Add required path & save it.
   [image: View IMAGE]

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

4. Run the following command to reload your shell configuration:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

After you have set the PATH for adb, you should be able to run the adb command from any terminal window.

Answer (score 8):

If you using zsh then you need do the add the following to your .zshrc

Steps:
Step 1: Open your .zshrc profile

```
open -e .zshrc
```

Step 2: Add the following to the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/${YourUser}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/${YourUser}/Library/Android/sdk
```

Step 3: Save the file and close.
Step 4: Reload the .zshrc

```
source .zshrc
```

Step 5: Check the devices connected

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are using Android Studio in MAC OS X , you could exec the following command in your terminal app:

```
echo 'alias adb="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/adb"' >> .bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

and next:

```
adb devices
```

and you should be showing a list with your android devices connected via USB cable in your MAC, for example something like this:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
deb7bed5        device
```

Comment: Can you just clarify what the exec $SHELL line does exactly? Newb here, never used that in a terminal before! :)

Comment: I run this command, because after edit the '.basrc' is necessary that restart the command line, and with this command you can restart without to close the terminal window

Answer (score 7):

## MAC Solution.

```
cd /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
./adb devices
```

Answer (score 6):

For macOS Users Updated to MacOs Catalina,

**~/.bash_profile** changed to **~/.zshrc**

So ,to run **adb** command and all other commands already exported to **~/.bash_profile**  easy walkaround is to export bash_profile to **zshrc**

To do that,

**1) Navigate to the home directory in finder**

**2) I used Cmd + Shift + . to show the hidden files in Finder**

**3) Create .zshrc file if already not exist**

**4) Add line "source ~/.bash_profile" without quotes**

**5) Save**

**6) Quit and open terminal**

start using **adb devices**

Comment: This, in combination with this solution: [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/58387314/3511695 ] finally seemed to work. Geeeeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a detailed manual:
http://codexpi.com/add-android-adb-path-mac-os-x-mavericks/

To sum this up:

1. Create and open the bash_profile file

   `touch .bash_profile`
   `open -e .bash_profile`
2. Add the path of the platform-tools folder (within the Android SDK)

   `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/PATH TO ANDROID SDK/platform-tools/`
3. Run the command `. .bash_profile` to update (no need to restart the terminal)

Comment: remove " after PATH=

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ZSH and have Android Studio 1.3:
1. Open .zshrc file (Located in your home directory, file is hidden so make sure you can see hidden files)
2. Add this line at the end: `alias adb="/Users/kamil/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"`
3. Quit terminal
4. Open terminal and type in `adb devices`
5. If it worked it will give you list of all connected devices

Answer (score 5):

Mac OS
Open Terminal

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Copy and paste:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

command + S for save.

Comment: Still getting `zsh: command not found: adb` after opening a new terminal window. EDIT: I just had to follow these steps afterwards: [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/59243688/3511695 ]

Answer (score 4):

If you are setting the path in Catalina use below command one after another in the terminal. It's working fine for me.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 4):

Download Android Platform Tools for macOS from:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Extract to your somewhere e.g `~/installs/platform-tools`

Add that folder to path by running:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/installs/platform-tools' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Either restart terminal or run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Assuming that you are using zsh.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting with some updated information from 2018.

Executable Binaries for Platform tools are made available for mac by Android here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Download these to your mac. Place them in a directory e.g. I placed in `~/Software/platform-tools`

**If you have root access**, the easiest way I have found on a mac is to add your directories to the list in `/etc/paths`. I like this way because after a few additions the `$PATH` starts to look too messy and hard to read, the `/etc/paths`has everything in separate line, clean and organized. **The downside is that you require root access.**

```
$ cat /etc/paths  # check contents of the file
$ sudo nano /etc/paths
```

Paste the full path of your platform-tools directory (something like `/Users/GodZilla/Software/platform-tools/adb`) at the end of this list and save. Quit and Open terminal again and check if it sees your platform-tools directory.

```
$ which adb
/Users/GodZilla/Software/platform-tools/adb
$ which fastboot
/Users/GodZilla/Software/platform-tools/fastboot
```

*If you don't have root access, just add the platform-tools directory to `$PATH` in your .bash_profile (or .zshenv if you use zsh) as other users have suggested.*

Answer (score 2):

This totally worked for me, after dickering around for a while after installing Android Studio:

1. Make sure you have the .bash_profile file.  This should be in your [username] directory.
2. From whatever directory you are on, type this:

   ```
   echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

Now, usually you will have this exact path, but if not, then use whatever path you have the platform-tools folder

3. From the directory where your .bash_profile resides, type this:

   ```
   . .bash_profile
   ```
4. Now type `adb devices`.  You should see a "List of devices attached" response.  Now you do not have to go to the platform-tools directory each and every time to type in the more cryptic command like, `./adb devices`!!!

Comment: it's a little easier to read for a newbie I think. maybe it could be added to the other?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I installed Android studio, and have some apps (rust lang) that changes the `~/.profile`, and adding `adb` to `~/.bash_profile` made the rust un-executable, so I made the changes to the `~/.profile` only, as:

```sh
$ echo 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.4-5871666
Installed as /Users/hasan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case : I did the following (on a mac) :

1. backed up the ".bash_profile" and ".profile"
2. cleared all the android related paths.
3. created the new paths but this time around, I dragged the respective folders : { /.../sdk, /.../tools, /.../platform-tools } into the terminal. I did this for both ".bash_profile" and ".profile".
4. Then after successfully saving the files each. I restarted the terminal just to be sure about the modifications I made.
5. I then went on to test if adb was responding now ...
   by typing :   (in terminal)         adb devices
6. I still had no luck (my devices) where not showing, then I restarted the adb, still.
7. I went on to do "android update adb" . This just killed and restarted the adb
8. I tried again still the devices wasnt showing.
9. I totally backed up my android device and resetted the whole phone back to factory default, went over to activate the device for development and allow for usb debugging in its settings > applications.

******** WORKED LIKE A CHARM ********

I tried again with the command "adb devices" and everything was back to normal the device was visible.

All the best. Just dont give up. It took me a lot of troubleshooting. All the best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have already downloaded SDK platform tools.

This command will set ADB locally. So if you close the terminal and open it again, ADB commands won't work until you run this command again.

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

These commands will set ADB globally. So once you run these commands no need to set them again next time.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh terminal do the following:

1) Open .zprofile file with the editor of your choice like "open -a xcode ~/.zprofile"

2) Add new PATH or Env Variable in .zprofile Save the file and quit the editor.

3) Execute your .zprofile to update your PATH: source ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 0):

**Add environment variable for Android Home Targetting Platform Tools**

`echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile`

**Restart Bash**

`source ~/.bash_profile`

**Now Check adb**

Simply type

`adb`

on terminal

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions, none of them where working for me.

In my case I had the Android Studio and the adb was correctly working but the Android Studio was not capable to detect the adb. These was because I installed it with homebrew in another directory, not the /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk but Usr/Library blabla

Apparently AS needed to have it in his route /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk (same place as in preferences SDK installation route)

So I deleted all the adb from my computer (I installed several) and executed these terminal commands:

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
adb devices
```

Well, after that, still wasn't working, because for some reason the route for the adb was /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools (yes, repeated) so I just copied the last platform-tools into the first directory with all the license files and started working.

Weird but true

Answer (score -1):

## MacPorts

It seems like `android-platform-tools` was first added to MacPorts only very recently — in 2018-10-20, under `java/android-platform-tools/Portfile`:

- https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=android
- https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/java/android-platform-tools/Portfile
- https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/7fde64249deb97c97edb37699f1ee8076c98d41a#diff-f03a90b4adeb82935eb39763ecd988f2

It would appear that it relies on a compiled binary that's provided by Google; it would appear that the source code for the binary might not be available.

## The `adb` binary

Reverse-engineering the `android-platform-tools/Portfile` from above reveals that the following archive is fetched from Google in order to build the port:

- https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-darwin.zip

The `abd` binary is pre-compiled, available in `platform-tools/adb` within the above archive, which is a `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`, as per [`file(1)`](http://mdoc.su/f/file.1).  It's ready to be used and doesn't seem to have any external dependencies (e.g., doesn't look like it depends on java or anything).

## Using `adb`

In order to use `adb` to restart the device, for example, in case the power button is stuck, the following steps could be used:

```
cd /tmp
curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-darwin.zip -o apt.zip
unzip apt.zip
./platform-tools/adb devices
./platform-tools/adb reboot
```

Upon first use since a reboot, you also have to first confirm the pairing with the phone through the **Allow USB debugging?** popup on the phone (phone has to have *USB debugging* enabled through the *Developer Options*, no root access required).

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Open Terminal

Step 2 : Run command :

```
 touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 3 : This will open textEdit file when you can add following command:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/Users/sharan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

> Blockquote

Note : sharan is my user name check that on y
our system and replace that with sharan rest will be same. You can also find that by opening android studio

```
   File->Project Structure..->SDK Location
```

Under  Android SDK location there is path of sdk copy that and paste that on file and save it by pressing Command+S

Comment: File saved then what?