# open android simulator with React Native by default

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to open react native app and simulator using one command..

i mean some thing like  : `react-native run-android --emulator 'PIXEL_API_27'`

i also try :

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"android": "react-native run-android --emulator 'PIXEL_API_27'",
"test": "jest"
```

},

and run command `npm run android` but its complaining that `error: unknown option`--simulator'`

i am very new with react native. pls help me ....

Comment: There is no such option in react-native cli. I would suggest you reading the following which will explain you how to launch the emulator in command line : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline . Then, you execute that command before the `run-android` one.

Answer (score 11):

There is currently no way to open a terminal by passing additional flags to `react-native run-android`.

So your problem is two fold. First how to run the emulator from the command line, and second how to chain that command with running your react-native project. Let's deal with them in that order.

**Opening the emulator from the command line**

It is possible to open an emulator via the command line. that is done with the `emulator @avd` command, replacing `@avd` with the name of your android virtual device. For example:

`emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27_x86`

To get the names of the installed android virtual devices on your machine run `emulator -list-avds`.

Now that your emulator is running let's get react-native running too.

**Running the emulator and then running react-native run-android**

I have found one issue with running the emulator from the command line, the emulator command keeps executing meaning that you cannot chain commands using `&&`. However you can run the emulator terminal in the background, by using `&` so we can chain the commands in the following way:

`emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27_x86 & react-native run-android`

If you are happy running the terminal in the background, this could be the solution for you.

For more settings for running the emulator from the command line see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

---

Be warned you may get errors when you try to run the emulator command. The most common that I have come across is the **PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.** This may require you to dive into your .bashrc or your .bash_profile to get the emulator command to behave. You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511666/5508175)

Comment: But its saying `'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: As I said you may have to play around with you `.bashrc` Or `.bash_profile`. You probably have commands missing from it. The following is for setting up adb on a Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x for windows this article has some suggestions https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial

Comment: @Amjad , For windows, make sure that `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\emulator` is in your `PATH` User variable. Restart `command prompt` or `powershell`, then run `emulator '@Nexus_5X_API_27_Android_8.1'` Where by `Nexus_5X_API_27_Android_8.1` is your _Android Virtual Device (AVD)_ name.