# I Can't locate adb on Android Studio 4

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-studio-4.0

I installed Android Studio version 4 but whenever I try to run the emulator I get the error "can't locate adb".
So far I made sure it's not blocked by my anti-virus
I replaced the adb.exe with the new one from SDK tools

But still, I can't get past that error. Any leads or clues on what could be wrong?

Comment: is ABD added to the path?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You have messed something with your installation. On Windows, if you download full package from https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads and install it, adb should be installed and automatically added to path. Otherwise, you can try to download command line tools only and install them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac, check this answer to help you find how to add adb to PATH.
[Set up adb on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x)

Or you could check out this [article](https://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378).

Answer (score 0):

This might be because no sdk is selected in project.
Go to file->project structure->project sdk
Now select an installed sdk from the list. It should solve the problem.