# error on running android emulator: spawn adb ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I created a new react native app by using the expo cli.
iOS Xcode Emulator is working fine but getting below error for android emulator

```
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
```

I tried to uninstall and install back expo-cli. Tried to delete the emulator and create a new one. None of them is working.

Answer (score 5):

I was in your same situation wherein I’d just installed expo and tried to run the app in an emulator on my Mac.

Apparently the problem was that ANDROID_HOME and adb weren’t set in my $PATH.

I solved it by referring to Option 3 (I already had android studio installed) of the top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x).   In case you want to know what I did, I use ohmyzsh by default so I did the following:

```
nano .zshrc
```

Add these two lines in the .zshrc file.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then run this in your terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Restart your terminal and now everything works!

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for hours. Fixing the $PATH fixed it. Upvoted.

Comment: Totally the same to my situation, using expo and met this error while started a preview, and I also using ohmyzsh. But the path of my Android/sdk is slightly different. So to somebody coming for the answer, here is the reminder, don't just copy and paste, change the path to your android sdk's path.

Comment: This answer help me to solve same problem on linux. Thanks