# Copy / Paste text Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

How do you copy/paste text from the `Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator` to your **development PC (desktop)**?

I saw that this is [possible (although elaborate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391160/paste-text-on-android-emulator) on the Android Emulator.

I would assume there should be a way to access the emulator's clipboard through VS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try starting the `Emulator` without `Debugging`?

Reference: [copy-and-paste in the emulator for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg588379%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: That article explains how to copy and past within the emulator, I did try that and it doesn't work. Thanks for the effort.