# How can I copy/pate multibyte characters on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, internationalization

I got to know how to copy/paste from command line tool at 
[Paste text on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391160/paste-text-on-android-emulator)

```
adb shell input keyboard text 'foo'
```

It works very well for ascii characters but it doesn't for multibyte characters.

```
adb shell input keyboard text 'あ'
```

Doesn't pass any character to emulator.

```
adb shell input keyboard text '\u3042'
```

Shows '\u3042' as it is.

Is there any way to pass multibyte characters to the emulator from command line correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to do what you want.

Digging in the sources, the input command line tool ends up calling KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD), and uses that KeyCharacterMap to map from characters to keys press / release events.

Since KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD does not cover the whole Unicode range, it is not possible to generate events for a lot of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Android Emulator (v25.3) can support copying & pasting multibyte characters. This was launched with [Android Studio 2.3](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/android-studio-2-3.html). Take a look at the screen recording of the behavior below...

[image]